# How can I remove the top and right axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Instead of the default "boxed" axis style I want to have only the left and bottom axis, i.e.:

```
+------+         |
|      |         |
|      |   --->  |
|      |         |
+------+         +-------
```

This should be easy, but I can't find the necessary options in the docs.

Comment: As per the `.spines` docstring: `ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)` removes all spines.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

This is the suggested Matplotlib 3 solution from the official website [HERE](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)

# Hide the right and top spines
ax.spines[['right', 'top']].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Additional question for beginners: where can you find this answer based on the Matplotlib API doc? If I go there: https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html I don't see any reference to the `spine` object, and I wouldn't have guessed this keyword.

Comment: @EricBurel I find the Matplotlib documentation poorly designed. I generally find it easier to understand its API from examples. This is why StackOverflow is so important! I wish the Matplotliob documentation was written with the clear and well-organized approach of Scipy and Numpy.

Comment: You can also use `ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)` (dot notation instead of brackets and quotes). `spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)` works too.

Comment: In newer matplotlib (mine is 3.3.4) spines is an ordered dict, so ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False) will turn off the right spine.

Answer (score 74):

Alternatively, this

```
def simpleaxis(ax):
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
    ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
```

seems to achieve the same effect on an axis without losing rotated label support.

(Matplotlib 1.0.1; solution inspired by [this](http://www.shocksolution.com/2011/08/removing-an-axis-or-both-axes-from-a-matplotlib-plot/)).

Answer (score 33):

[edit] matplotlib in now (2013-10) on version 1.3.0 which includes this

That ability was actually just added, and you need the Subversion version for it.  You can see the example code [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html).

I am just updating to say that there's a better [example](https://github.com/ericliang/matplotlib/blob/master/tags/v0_99_0/examples/axes_grid/simple_axisline3.py) online now.  Still need the Subversion version though, there hasn't been a release with this yet.

[edit] Matplotlib 0.99.0 RC1 was just released, and includes this capability.

Comment: Make sure you read the warning at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html about tick-mark support being incomplete before you try and use the above with e.g rotated labels though!

Comment: It looks like it depends on how you construct the axis. The axes generated by ``mpl.subplots`` cannot be used this way?

Comment: The example link is now broken.

Answer (score 33):

If you need to remove it from all your plots, you can remove spines in style settings (style sheet or rcParams). E.g:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] = False
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
```

If you want to remove all spines:

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.left'] = False
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] = False
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.bottom'] = False
```

Answer (score 26):

<sub>(This is more of an extension comment, in addition to the comprehensive answers here.)</sub>

---

Note that we can hide each of these three elements independently of each other:

- To hide the border (aka "spine"): `ax.set_frame_on(False)` or `ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)`
- To hide the ticks: `ax.tick_params(top=False)`
- To hide the labels: `ax.tick_params(labeltop=False)`

Answer (score 21):

Library Seaborn has this built in with function `.despine()`.

Just add:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

Now create your graph. And add at the end:

```
sns.despine()
```

If you look at some of the default parameter values of the function it removes the top and right spine and keeps the bottom and left spine:

```
sns.despine(top=True, right=True, left=False, bottom=False)
```

Check out further documentation here:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.despine.html

Comment: This is definitely the version to work well when using multiple axis or figures!

Answer (score 12):

If you don't need ticks and such (e.g. for plotting qualitative illustrations) you could also use this quick workaround:

Make the axis invisible (e.g. with `plt.gca().axison = False`) and then draw them manually with `plt.arrow`.

Comment: this seems to remove the spines but leave the tick marks in place. Any idea how to remove the ticks as well?

Comment: @Rob: You are right, I actually used a different solution in the script I was thinking of. I changed my answer, this should now work, but in general the accepted solution above is better.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this in a non-global way is using the [`matplotlib.pyplot.rc_context`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rc_context.html) context manager, as follows:

```
with plt.rc_context({
    "axes.spines.right": False,
    "axes.spines.top": False,
}):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer is good if all you want to do is turn off the axes lines, I would suggest getting familiar with the `.set()` function as you can pass additional kwargs controlling the line style, thickness, etc etc, making your code more flexible and re-usable. It also cuts down on the number of matplotlib functions you need to learn.

Op can do this:

```
ax.spines.top.set(visible=False)
ax.spines.right.set(visible=False)
```

but you can just as easily do something like this:

```
ax.spines.right.set(color='red', linestyle='--', linewidth=2, position=['data',2])
ax.spines.top.set(color='red', linestyle='--', linewidth=2, position=['data',5])
```

[image: Using spines.set() to do things]

See documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html#matplotlib.spines.Spine.set).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to apply this on a frequent basis, you can also create a style sheet as described [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-style-sheets) and use these settings:

```
axes.spines.left:   True
axes.spines.bottom: True
axes.spines.top:    False
axes.spines.right:  False
```