# Borderless matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to save matplotlib graphs without the border around the frame while keeping the background not transparent?

Setting the frame to 'off' as I show in the code below does not work as this removes the background making it transparent whereas I want to retain the white background, just without the borders.

```
a = fig.gca()  
a.set_frame_on(False)
```

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do. If the border can be removed then I can draw the x-axis line separately.

[image]

All suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A similar question was asked here: [How can I remove the top and right axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925024/564538). A Google search for "hide axes matplotlib" gives that as the 5th link.

Remove the spines:

```
x = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 1000)
y = sin(x)
fig, ax = subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.grid(axis='y')
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

A simpler way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False) #remove ticks
plt.box(False) #remove box
```

Comment: In case you are using `Axes` object: `ax.set_frame_on(False)`

Answer (score 11):

You can try to use `ax.spines`. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

If you want to remove all spines (and probably ticks as well), you can do

```
[s.set_visible(False) for s in ax.spines.values()]
[t.set_visible(False) for t in ax.get_xticklines()]
[t.set_visible(False) for t in ax.get_yticklines()]
```

Comment: `ax.tick_params(left=False, right=False)` and so on, is a bit easier than looping over each set of tick lines.