# Matplotlib odd subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have to plot a figure with 11 subpots as you can see below. But as it is an odd number, i dont know how to deal the subplot (4,3,12) to remove it... and place the 2 last plots on the center
Moreover i would like to increse the subplot size as the space is too important. The code is below.

[image]

The code is :

```
plt.close()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3)

plt.tight_layout(pad=0.05, w_pad=0.001, h_pad=2.0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(431) # creates first axis
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax1.tick_params(labelsize=8) 
i1 = ax1.imshow(IIIm,cmap='hot',extent=(0,2000,0,2000),vmin=-0.2,vmax=-0.1)
i11 = ax1.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
cb1=plt.colorbar(i1,ax=ax1,ticks=[-0.2,-0.15,-0.1],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.3f')
cb1.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
ax1.set_title("$n = -3$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)


ax2 = plt.subplot(432) # creates second axis
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
i2=ax2.imshow(IIm,cmap='hot',extent=(0,2000,0,2000),vmin=-0.1,vmax=0.1)
i22 = ax2.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
ax2.set_title("$n = -2$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticklabels([])
cb2=plt.colorbar(i2,ax=ax2,ticks=[-0.1,0.0,0.1],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.3f')
cb2.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)

ax3 = plt.subplot(433) # creates first axis
ax3.set_xticks([])
ax3.set_yticks([])
i3 = ax3.imshow(Im,cmap='hot',extent=(0,2000,0,2000),vmin=-1,vmax=-0.2)
i33 = ax3.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
ax3.set_title("$n = -1$ ", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
cb3=plt.colorbar(i3,ax=ax3,ticks=[-1,-0.6,-0.2],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.3f')
ax3.set_xticklabels([])
ax3.set_yticklabels([])
cb3.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
#plt.gcf().tight_layout()





#plt.tight_layout(pad=0.05, w_pad=0.001, h_pad=2.0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(434) # creates first axis
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax1.tick_params(labelsize=8) 
i1 = ax1.imshow(ZV_0_modeI,extent=(0,2000,0,2000),cmap=plt.cm.hot,origin="lower", vmin=-1, vmax=1)
i11 = ax1.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
cb1=plt.colorbar(i1,ax=ax1,ticks=[-1,0, 1],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.2f')
cb1.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
ax1.set_title("$ n = 0$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)


ax2 = plt.subplot(435) # creates second axis
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
i2=ax2.imshow(I,cmap='hot',extent=(0,2000,0,2000), vmin=-1, vmax=1)
i22 = ax2.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
ax2.set_title("$n = 1$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticklabels([])
cb2=plt.colorbar(i2,ax=ax2,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,ticks=[-1,0,1],format='%.2f')
cb2.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)

ax3 = plt.subplot(436) # creates first axis
ax3.set_xticks([])
ax3.set_yticks([])
i3 = ax3.imshow(II,cmap='hot',extent=(0,2000,0,2000),vmin=-1,vmax=1)
i33 = ax3.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
ax3.set_title("$n = 2$ ", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
cb3=plt.colorbar(i3,ax=ax3,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,ticks=[-1.,0,1.],format='%.2f')
ax3.set_xticklabels([])
ax3.set_yticklabels([])
cb3.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
plt.gcf().tight_layout()




plt.tight_layout(pad=0.05, w_pad=0.001, h_pad=2.0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(437) # creates first axis
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax1.tick_params(labelsize=8) 
i1 = ax1.imshow(III,cmap=plt.cm.hot,origin="lower",extent=(0,2000,0,2000),vmin=-1, vmax=1)
i11 = ax1.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
cb1=plt.colorbar(i1,ax=ax1,ticks=[-1,0, 1],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.2f')
cb1.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
ax1.set_title("$ n = 3$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)

ax2 = plt.subplot(438) # creates second axis
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
i2=ax2.imshow(IV,cmap='hot',extent=(0,2000,0,2000), vmin=-1, vmax=1)
i22 = ax2.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
ax2.set_title("$n = 4$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticklabels([])
cb2=plt.colorbar(i2,ax=ax2,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,ticks=[-1,0,1],format='%.2f')
cb2.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)

ax3 = plt.subplot(439) # creates first axis
ax3.set_xticks([])
ax3.set_yticks([])
i3 = ax3.imshow(V,cmap='hot',extent=(0,2000,0,2000),vmin=-1,vmax=1)
i33 = ax3.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
ax3.set_title("$n = 5$ ", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
cb3=plt.colorbar(i3,ax=ax3,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,ticks=[-1.,0,1.],format='%.2f')
ax3.set_xticklabels([])
ax3.set_yticklabels([])
cb3.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
plt.gcf().tight_layout()




plt.tight_layout(pad=0.05, w_pad=0.001, h_pad=2.0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(4,3,10) # creates first axis
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax1.tick_params(labelsize=8) 
i1 = ax1.imshow(VI,cmap=plt.cm.hot,origin="lower",extent=(0,2000,0,2000),vmin=-1, vmax=1)
i11 = ax1.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
cb1=plt.colorbar(i1,ax=ax1,ticks=[-1,0, 1],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.2f')
cb1.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
ax1.set_title("$ n = 6$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)

ax2 = plt.subplot(4,3,11) # creates second axis
ax2.set_xticks([0])
ax2.set_yticks([])
i2=ax2.imshow(VII,cmap='hot',extent=(0,2000,0,2000), vmin=-1, vmax=1)
i22 = ax2.plot((0,600),(1000,1000),'k-',linewidth=3)
ax2.set_title("$n = 7$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticklabels([])
cb2=plt.colorbar(i2,ax=ax2,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,ticks=[-1,0,1],format='%.2f')
cb2.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)


plt.savefig('filtre.png', dpi=250,bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: With `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3)` you have created that axes instance, so you need to hide it manually, maybe this helps: https://codeyarns.com/2015/06/29/how-to-hide-axis-of-plot-in-matplotlib/  EDIT: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603959/borderless-matplotlib-plots

Comment: Why create all the `axes` without using them?  A simple `fig=pl.figure()` with the rest of the code unchanged should fix this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of achieving what you require is to use matplotlibs [subplot2grid](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) feature. Using this you can set the total size of the grid (4,3 in your case) and choose to only plot data in certain subplots in this grid. Below is a simplified example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2]
y = [3,4]

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (0, 1))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (0, 2))
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (1, 0))
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (1, 1))
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (1, 2))
ax7 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (2, 0))
ax8 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (2, 1))
ax9 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (2, 2))
ax10 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (3, 0))
ax11 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (3, 1))

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.3, hspace = 0.3) #make the figure look better

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y)
ax3.plot(x,y)
ax4.plot(x,y)
ax5.plot(x,y)
ax6.plot(x,y)
ax7.plot(x,y)
ax8.plot(x,y)
ax9.plot(x,y)
ax10.plot(x,y)
ax11.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

This produces the figure:

[image]

Comment: Nice thanks for your contribution! and if you wante to center the 2 last ones?

Comment: I'm not sure about centering the bottom two but you can increase the size of the last subplot by adding `colspan = 2` to the `ax11` definition like `ax11 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 3), (3, 1),colspan=2)`. This will widen the figure to use the remaining space.

Comment: Not very concluding with the "colspan"  but thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: To _centre_ the the bottom row you can create 6 _columns_ by using `subplot2grid((4,6),....` and use `colspan=2` for all plots and use 0,2,4 as column index for the top three rows and 1,3 as column index for the bottom row.

Comment: Do you know how one could reference the figure object given this code?

Comment: @jglad Either create the figure before the subplots using `fig=plt.figure()`. Or after creating the subplots you can get the current figure using `plt.gcf()`

Answer (score 4):

Just don't plot anything, but **set the axis off**

```
ax = plt.subplot(4,3,12)
ax.axis('off')
```

You can use a loop if necessary like this

```
images = [rgb, depth, depth, rgb, rgb]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, columns)
    for index, axis in enumerate(axes.reshape(-1)):
        if index < no_of_images:
            axis.imshow(images[index])
        axis.axis('off')
```

[image]