# Live update several plots in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to display history of CPU and RAM usage in Jupyter Notebook in real time. Something like this (Process Explorer in Windows):
[image: process explorer plots]

I don't interactivity so I use `matplotlib` in inline mode. I run a separate background thread and try to update two different plots from there. It works well with one plot but the second one blinks and has duplicates.

[image]

Here's a [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/Winand/bf2ce049d23bf3e8a1f5bff337817442) (also I pickle/unpickle plot so I can initialize it only once and reuse later).

Installed packages:

```
ipykernel                         5.1.3
ipywidgets                        7.5.1
jupyter                           1.0.0
jupyter-core                      4.6.1
matplotlib                        3.1.1 
notebook                          6.0.0
```

```py
import pickle
import threading
import time

import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def init_history_plot():
    """
    Create plot template (dump)
    
    Returns: pickled str
    """
#     plt.figure(figsize=(15, 1.2))
#     ax = plt.axes()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 1.2))
    # Y axis min-max
    ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
#     ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.grid(axis='y')
    # right tick labels https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369977
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    # hide ticks https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707647
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    # borders https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361819
    # for i in ax.spines.values():  # 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'
    #     ax.spines[i].set_visible(False)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603959/borderless-matplotlib-plots
    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    dat = pickle.dumps(fig)
    plt.close()
    return dat

def load_figure(dump):
    """
    Load Figure from dump
    
    Returns: (Figure, Axes)
    """
    # https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/231
    import ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline as back_inline
    import matplotlib.backends.backend_agg as back_agg
    back_inline.new_figure_manager_given_figure = back_agg.new_figure_manager_given_figure
    figure = pickle.loads(dump)
    # https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17627/
    figure._cachedRenderer = None
    return figure, figure.axes[0]


template_fig = init_history_plot()

btn_start = widgets.ToggleButton(description="Start thread")
plt1_parent = widgets.Output()
plt2_parent = widgets.Output()
_interface = widgets.VBox(children=[btn_start, plt1_parent, plt2_parent])

def worker():
    while btn_start.value:
        with plt1_parent:
            plt1_parent.clear_output(wait=True)
            fig, ax = load_figure(template_fig)
            dat = np.random.normal(scale=20, size=50) + 50
            ax.plot(dat, color='green')
            plt.show()
        # THE FOLLOWING BLOCK BLINKS
        with plt2_parent:
            plt2_parent.clear_output(wait=True)
            fig, ax = load_figure(template_fig)
            dat = np.random.normal(scale=20, size=50) + 50
            ax.plot(dat, color='red')
            plt.show()
        ############################
        time.sleep(1)

def start_thread(_):
    if btn_start.value:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        thread.start()
btn_start.observe(start_thread, 'value')

_interface
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is really cool, and so I greedily stole it because I also want to have plots that live-update in a Jupyter notebook without blocking the kernel.

Anyway, the weird flickering was bothering me as well. I tried switching from threading to asyncio, simply because I am more familiar with asyncio than threading, and that actually seems to have solved the problem! Though I have no idea why.

Try:

```
import pickle
import asyncio
import time

import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def init_history_plot():
    """
    Create plot template (dump)
    
    Returns: pickled str
    """
#     plt.figure(figsize=(15, 1.2))
#     ax = plt.axes()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 1.2))
    # Y axis min-max
    ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
#     ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.grid(axis='y')
    # right tick labels https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369977
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    # hide ticks https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707647
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    # borders https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361819
    # for i in ax.spines.values():  # 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'
    #     ax.spines[i].set_visible(False)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603959/borderless-matplotlib-plots
    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    dat = pickle.dumps(fig)
    plt.close()
    return dat

def load_figure(dump):
    """
    Load Figure from dump
    
    Returns: (Figure, Axes)
    """
    # https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/231
    import ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline as back_inline
    import matplotlib.backends.backend_agg as back_agg
    back_inline.new_figure_manager_given_figure = back_agg.new_figure_manager_given_figure
    figure = pickle.loads(dump)
    # https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17627/
    figure._cachedRenderer = None
    return figure, figure.axes[0]


template_fig = init_history_plot()

btn_start = widgets.ToggleButton(description="Start thread")
plt1_parent = widgets.Output()
plt2_parent = widgets.Output()
_interface = widgets.VBox(children=[btn_start, plt1_parent, plt2_parent])

async def worker():
    while btn_start.value:
        with plt1_parent:
            plt1_parent.clear_output(wait=True)
            fig, ax = load_figure(template_fig)
            dat = np.random.normal(scale=20, size=50) + 50
            ax.plot(dat, color='green')
            plt.show()
        with plt2_parent:
            plt2_parent.clear_output(wait=True)
            fig, ax = load_figure(template_fig)
            dat = np.random.normal(scale=20, size=50) + 50
            ax.plot(dat, color='red')
            plt.show()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

def start_thread(_):
    if btn_start.value:
        task = asyncio.create_task(worker())
btn_start.observe(start_thread, 'value')

_interface
```