# Plot values but also labels on a single axis (1D scatter plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

**How to plot not only values but also the labels on an axis with `matplotlib` with a dict like this:**

```
D = {'label1': 7.33, 'label2': 7.12, 'label3': 4.26, 'label4': 6.98}
```

**?**

it should output

[image]

This goal is to see the outliers very easily graphically, i.e. a 1D-scatter plot, like this:

[image]

but with a label near each point.

Comment: Thew optimal strategy depends on what kind of data you show (i.e. whether each data point gets its own label or not). The question does not provide enough detail to find out though.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, each data point (~ 20 points) gets its own label.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the minor and major ticklabels to alternate between showing the label above and below the axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

D = {'label1': 7.33, 'label2': 7.12, 'label3': 4.26, 'label4': 6.98}

labs, vals = zip(*sorted([(k,v) for k,v in D.items()], key=lambda t: t[1] ))
ticks = ["{}\n{}".format(k,v) for k,v in zip(labs,vals)]

ax.set_xticks(vals[::2])
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks[::2])
ax.set_xticks(vals[1::2], minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks[1::2], minor=True, va="bottom")

ax.tick_params(which="minor", direction="in", pad=-10 )


plt.plot(vals, list(range(len(vals))))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How to plot the horizontal axis only, and no y-axis, no curve, no boundary rectangle etc.? i.e. just like the example image in the question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925024/how-can-i-remove-the-top-and-right-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: This removes the boundary box, but the y-axis is still there, how to have an horizontal axis only? Something like this but with labels for each point: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:R-US_state_areas-1D_jitter.svg

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998430/remove-xticks-in-a-matplotlib-plot

Comment: It seems that [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) is a more natural way to do it (i.e. no need to create a 2D graphic and then manually remove the box, remove the y-axis, etc.)