# How to hide the axes but keep the grid?

Tags: matlab, plot, hide, customization, matlab-figure

If we have a figure

```
plot(x, y);
grid on;
```

We get something like this

[image]

But now, I wish to hide the axis, so I tried the commands below:

```
axis off
set(gca,'xtick',[])
set(gca,'ytick',[])
set(gca,'visible','off')
```

Together they successfully hid the axis, **but the grid was also deleted**!

`set(gca, 'xticklabel', [])` can hide the label, but not the axis.

So, how do I hide the **axis**, **ticks** and **labels**, leaving **only** the **plot** and **grid**?

Comment: I answered from a python / matplotlib perspective (didn't read clearly enough...), but am not sure it's true in Matlab itself, so I deleted the answer. For python's matplotlib, see [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html). Perhaps this will help.

Comment: @BrendanCox Thank u, I saw your answer, but even in matplotib, I saw you still didn't hide the axes.

Comment: Have you tried hiding the `ticklabels` but not the `ticks`?

Comment: @avermaet yes, it won't delete the grid, but the axes are still there.

Comment: What do you mean by axes? The `XTicks`? Or `box off`

Comment: Ah, so you want to hide the axis lines themselves? In matplotlib, this appears to be done via the `spines` property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925024/how-can-i-remove-the-top-and-right-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @avermaet both of them. `box off` for all four borders (top, bottom, left, right).

Comment: Is `figure; plot(x,y); ax=gca; ax.GridColor='b';` working for you ? If so, you could try to change the axes color to the same color as the background so they aren't visible. And then make the grid black or whatever color you want using the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `Xcolor` and `Ycolor` to `none` so the axis won't be displayed:

```
%dummy data
x = [-5:.1:5];
y = normpdf(x,0,1);
plot(x, y);

%grid on
grid on;

%Set the axis color to none.
set(gca,'XColor','none','Ycolor','none')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood what you wanted to achieve, but if this is what you meant,

[image]

here's how to do it:

```matlab
function [] = q57076281()
% Plot some data with a grid:
x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
y = sin(x);
figure(); hP = plot(x,y); hAx = hP.Parent; 
grid(hAx, 'on');

% Remove the box:
box(hAx, 'off'); 

% Hide the labels:
set(hAx, 'XTickLabel', [], 'YTickLabel', []);

% Hide the axes:
hXl = struct(hAx.XAxis).Axle; hXl.Visible = 'off';
hXl = struct(hAx.YAxis).Axle; hXl.Visible = 'off';

% Hide the ticks:
hAx.TickLength = [0,0];
```

Comment: That `struct` wrapper trick is neat for direct property referencing, but throws a warning (in R2017b at least). It would probably be better practise to use `hXl = get( hAx.XAxis, 'Axle' );`. Interestingly, replacing the intermediate variable `hXl` with a direct `set` command for the `Visible` property doesn't seem to work...