# "fontsize" parameter in matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel not working?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm building a plot on which I've hidden the top and right axes with:
(following the official example at https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/simple_axisline3.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axisartist-simple-axisline3-py)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import Axes
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(axes_class=Axes)

ax.axis["right", "top"].set_visible(False)

x_range = np.linspace(10, 20)
ax.plot(x_range, x_range+10)
```

Following that, I'm trying to set a custom fontsize for my x and y axes labels.
Normally it's simply done with:

```
ax.set_xlabel("A (unit A)", fontsize=50)
ax.set_ylabel("B (unit B)", fontsize=50)
```

However, no effect is to be seen on the fontsize. Please see the
[figure output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW6w9.png). No error is returned.

I guess the Axes subclass I'm calling from mpl_toolkits has a different way of doing so, but I did not manage how to do it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I would not use a toolbox for this.  You can do the same thing w a normal axes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925024/how-can-i-remove-the-top-and-right-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you @JodyKlymak.
spines instead of a toolbox is so simple. That's what I'm looking for.